# mysqli SUM and MAX results

Tags: mysql

hi guys im having trouble understanding how to get a MAX() and a SUM() from a Database

my database have 3 colums id - stuff - score looks like this

id-stuf-score

1-1-2

1-1-3

1-2-1

1-2-3

1-3-1

1-3-3

i need to make a

MAX(score) where stuff=1 and id = 1

MAX(score) where stuff=2 and id = 1

MAX(score) where stuff=3 and id = 1
.

.

etc

and then a 
SUM(score) all the MAX(score)

i have hundred of rows and i cant think of a way to make it happens

Comment: I suggest you to split your task into 3 queries. Then sum the results.

Comment: @user4035 it can be done in a single call.

Comment: any example can be usefull and appreciated, im having a headache thinking how to make it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `group by` to get your max scores, then sum the results.

**Records in Table**

I added a few more records to so the `max(score)` wouldn't be the same for every `stuf`.

```
mysql> select * from stuff;
+------+------+-------+
| id   | stuf | score |
+------+------+-------+
|    1 |    1 |     2 |
|    1 |    1 |     3 |
|    1 |    2 |     1 |
|    1 |    2 |     3 |
|    1 |    3 |     1 |
|    1 |    3 |     3 |
|    1 |    3 |     4 |
|    1 |    3 |     1 |
|    1 |    2 |     5 |
|    1 |    2 |     1 |
+------+------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Group By**

```
mysql> select id, max(score) as max_score from stuff group by stuf;
+------+-----------+
| id   | max_score |
+------+-----------+
|    1 |         3 |
|    1 |         5 |
|    1 |         4 |
+------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Sum It Up**

```
mysql> select sum(max_score) from (select id, max(score) as max_score 
       from stuff group by stuf) sum_me;
+----------------+
| sum(max_score) |
+----------------+
|             12 |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**One Note**

Keep in mind that if you have more ids then you will need to limit your query to whichever id you are interested in or appropriately group the last query.

```
mysql> select id, sum(max_score) from (select id, max(score) as max_score 
       from stuff group by id, stuf) sum_me group by id;
```

Answer (score 2):

make subquery table derivatives for each thing you need the max of, then add them all together.

```
SELECT SUM(a.max+b.max+c.max) as total
FROM (
    (
        SELECT MAX(score) as max
        FROM tablename
        WHERE stuff = 1 AND id = 1
    ) as a,
    (
        SELECT MAX(score) as max
        FROM tablename
        WHERE stuff = 2 AND id = 1
    ) as b,
    (
        SELECT MAX(score) as max
        FROM tablename
        WHERE stuff = 3 AND id = 1
    ) as c
);
```

Output:

```
_____________
|   total   |
+-----------+
|   12345   |
+-----------+
```

Comment: my problem is my rows, i got more that 200 rows thats gonna make it really hard to make

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
    SELECT SUM(a.max) as total
    FROM (
    (
        SELECT MAX(score) as max
        FROM tablename
        GROUP BY stuf, id
    ) as a
);
```